# Subquery no Banco Informix

Tags: sql, query, informix

Tenho uma consulta que busca as vendas de um período:

```
SELECT  cxpdvend.filial, 
        cxpdvend.dtpedido, 
        cxpdvend.pedvenda,
        ciendere.nro_endere, 
        cipessoa.nomepessoa, 
        ciendere.celular,
        cxpdvend.codagente, 
        cxpdvend.modelo, 
        cxpdvend.chassis, 
        (cxpdvend.valor-cxpdvend.valordesc) AS venda, 
        cxpdparc.formapgto
FROM cipessoa
INNER JOIN ciendere ON cipessoa.cgccpf = ciendere.cgccpf
INNER JOIN cxpdvend ON ciendere.nro_endere = cxpdvend.nro_endere
INNER JOIN cxcadast ON cxpdvend.chassis = cxcadast.chassis
INNER JOIN cxpdparc ON cxpdvend.pedvenda = cxpdparc.pedvenda
```

E uma outra que busca o custo desta venda:

```
SELECT cttransa.mvtotransacao, 
        cttransa.tipotransacao, 
        cnnfcapa.dtnota, 
        cnnfitem.chassis, 
        cnnfitem.valoritem
FROM cnnfcapa 
INNER JOIN cnnfitem ON cnnfcapa.id_nfcapa = cnnfitem.id_nfcapa
INNER JOIN cttransa ON cnnfcapa.transacao = cttransa.transacao
WHERE cttransa.mvtotransacao="E"
AND cttransa.tipotransacao=10
```

Eu gostaria de incluir na primeira consulta o custo de compra do chassi que é obtido na segunda consulta.

Estou tentando fazer uma subquery mas está retornando erro de sintaxe.

Estou tentando assim:

```
SELECT cxpdvend.filial, 
        cxpdvend.dtpedido, 
        cxpdvend.pedvenda,
        ciendere.nro_endere, 
        cipessoa.nomepessoa, 
        ciendere.celular,
        cxpdvend.codagente, 
        cxpdvend.modelo, 
        cxpdvend.chassis, 
        (cxpdvend.valor-cxpdvend.valordesc) AS venda, 
        cxpdparc.formapgto
FROM cipessoa 
(MULTISET(  SELECT cttransa.mvtotransacao, 
                    cttransa.tipotransacao, 
                    cnnfcapa.dtnota, 
                    cnnfitem.chassis, 
                    cnnfitem.valoritem
            FROM cnnfcapa 
            INNER JOIN cnnfitem ON cnnfcapa.id_nfcapa = cnnfitem.id_nfcapa
            INNER JOIN cttransa ON cnnfcapa.transacao = cttransa.transacao
            WHERE cttransa.mvtotransacao="E"
                    AND cttransa.tipotransacao=10)
INNER JOIN ciendere ON cipessoa.cgccpf = ciendere.cgccpf
INNER JOIN cxpdvend ON ciendere.nro_endere = cxpdvend.nro_endere
INNER JOIN cxcadast ON cxpdvend.chassis = cxcadast.chassis
INNER JOIN cxpdparc ON cxpdvend.pedvenda = cxpdparc.pedvenda
```

Comment: Qual o nome do erro que está retornando?

Comment: Como o "custo" se relaciona a "venda" ?

Comment: Olá Danilo. Está retornando Erro de sintaxe (201: A syntax error has occured

Comment: Motta, obrigado pela resposta. O custo e a venda estão relacionados pelo chassi

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá, tem alguns pontos a serem observados no seu código:

1. **MULTISET**: Você não precisa dessa cláusula para fazer um subselect no informix;
2. **ALIAS**: Seu subselect não tem alias e ele precisa de um para fazer join com as tabelas externas;
3. **ON**: Seu subselect, não tem cláusula `ON` com os campos que fazem o join do subselect com as tabelas externas;
4. **JOIN**: Como seu subselect precisa fazer `INNER JOIN` ou `LEFT JOIN` com uma tabela externa, ele precisa ficar localizado após a tabela na qual ele fará o `JOIN`, portanto, o subselect deverá ficar abaixo da tabela `cxcadast` ou da `cxpdvend`, dependendo de qual delas você utilizará para fazer o JOIN;
5. **ASPAS DUPLAS**: As aspas duplas servem como delimitar de nomes de colunas quando estas possuem espaços ou caracteres especiais ou acentos, por exemplo, se uma coluna da tabela tivesse o nome de `NUMERO NOTA`, esse espaço entre as palavras impossibilitaria o banco de dados de compreender o que significa, para que entendesse, teria que escrever `"NUMERO NOTA"` com as aspas duplas. Se você está lidando com dados tipo *string* na consulta SQL, como ali na parte `mvtotransacao = 'E'`, somente utilize aspas simples, caso contrário o banco entende que é um nome de coluna e não o tipo de dados *string*;
6. **CHASSI**: Verifique se o nome da coluna `chassis` existe mesmo na tabela `cnnfitem` pois ela pode ter outro nome, por exemplo `mercadoria`;
7. **JOIN**: Verifique também se utilizará `INNER JOIN` ou `LEFT JOIN` na tabela externa anterior ao subselect, pois utilizando `INNER JOIN` não trará as vendas que, por ventura, não possuam valor de custo, enquanto que usando `LEFT JOIN`, você trará todas as vendas, porém somente aquelas que possuem custo de compra terão o campo preenchido com valor e as que não possuem ficarão com o campo nulo.

Segue abaixo o SQL alterado conforme as pontuações acima:

```
    SELECT cxpdvend.filial, 
       cxpdvend.dtpedido, 
       cxpdvend.pedvenda,
       ciendere.nro_endere, 
       cipessoa.nomepessoa, 
       ciendere.celular,
       cxpdvend.codagente, 
       cxpdvend.modelo, 
       cxpdvend.chassis, 
       (cxpdvend.valor-cxpdvend.valordesc) AS venda, 
       cxpdparc.formapgto,
       cp.valoritem as compra
  FROM cipessoa 
       INNER JOIN ciendere ON cipessoa.cgccpf = ciendere.cgccpf
       INNER JOIN cxpdvend ON ciendere.nro_endere = cxpdvend.nro_endere
       INNER JOIN cxcadast ON cxpdvend.chassis = cxcadast.chassis
       INNER JOIN cxpdparc ON cxpdvend.pedvenda = cxpdparc.pedvenda
       LEFT JOIN ( SELECT cttransa.mvtotransacao, 
                          cttransa.tipotransacao, 
                          cnnfcapa.dtnota, 
                          cnnfitem.chassis, 
                          cnnfitem.valoritem
                     FROM cnnfcapa 
                          INNER JOIN cnnfitem ON cnnfcapa.id_nfcapa = cnnfitem.id_nfcapa
                          INNER JOIN cttransa ON cnnfcapa.transacao = cttransa.transacao
                    WHERE cttransa.mvtotransacao = 'E'
                      AND cttransa.tipotransacao = 10
                    ) cp ON cp.chassis = cxcadast.chassis
```